# Calculating the value of a definite integral knowing the value of the integrand and its derivative on the boundaries.

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals, gre-exam

I do not know how the givens are useful in solving this question:

> [image]

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Use integration by parts where $u=x$ and $dv=p^{"}(x)dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employ integration by parts.

Note in general:

$$\int_a^b fg'=\bigg[fg\bigg]_a^b-\int_a^b f'g$$

Thus, let $f=x$ and $g'=p''(x)$

$$\therefore \int_0^2 xp''(x)dx=\bigg[xp'(x)\bigg]_0^2-\int_0^2 p'(x)$$

$$=2p'(2)-(p(2)-p(0))=2(-1)-(3-3)=-2$$